# Database Functions Working Until Deployed on Azure

Tags: azure, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database, code-migration

I have an MVC application that I've deployed to Azure. Offline it works with no issue with the code first development. However when deployed to Azure it just gives me a non-de-script Error advising me that there's been an error.

I have a look on the management console for further information but was only able to find an error telling me a fatal error had occurred causing a 500 error. Everything else works on the site with no issue it's just when I'm trying to do anything with the database attached to it.

To publish the app I used the downloaded publish settings from the server so I know connection string and what not are all fine. I've also set up code migrations to fill in gaps in the code first dev work so I can see what I'm missing and I don't know where to go now without a more detailed error message?

Any ideas on where I can possibly look next to try and solve this?

Comment: Option 1. Add a global exception handler to get the actual exception and then log/email it to yourself.
Option 2. Add custom error page that displays the actual error and stack dump.

Comment: What's the exception message? FYI if you don't see the error you can show error messages by setting customErrors to Off in web.config. More info at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: That's great that allowed me to see the error and fix it :)